# ASP.NET MVCで ModelのList型の値をJavaScript で使いたい

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net

ASP.NET MVC で Model のList型の値を JavaScript でJsonデータとして参照したいので、
色々なサイトを参考に以下のように記述しました。

↓ View.cshtml の中へ記述

```
<Script type="text/javascript">
  @{
     var value = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.employees);
  }
  var employees = @value;
</script>
```

↑  ↑  ↑
JavaScriptのメンバ変数で受ける最後の行で、エラーが出ます。
エラーは「SCRIPT1028: 識別子、文字列または数がありません」
これを回避するには、どうしたらよいでしょうか。

メンバ変数の中身を確認すると、以下のように表示されます。

```
var employees = [{&quot;year&quot;:&quot;2001&quot;,&quot;month&quot;:&quot;03&quot;},{&quot;year&quot;:&quot;2002&quot;,&quot;month&quot;:&quot;04&quot;},{&quot;year&quot;:&quot;1999&quot;,&quot;month&quot;:&quot;10&quot;}];
```

" を「"」に変換したら、正しい値が入っているように思います。

```
var employees = [{"year":"2001","month":"03"},{"year":"2002","month":"04"},{"year":"1999","month":"10"}];
```

IE11の問題なのでしょうか。原因や回避方法をご存知でしたら教えてください。
よろしくお願いいたします。